# I couldn’t understand 3 things in normalized inputs and initial weights video?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

In this video https://www.udacity.com/course/viewer#!/c-ud730/l-6370362152/m-7119160655 it talks about zero mean and equal variance in our cross-entropy function I cannot understand where is zero mean and variance. Could someone give me an example to explain it? It also talks about initializing weights using normal distribution, could someone explain it to me how? And in the end it talks about taking derivatives with respect to weights and biases and then subtracting the values of weights and biases and moving in a loop. Could you explain this to me? I'm very confused!!

Answer (score 0):

these are basic statistics questions: you can find many resources on them.

A quick summary:

zero mean:   Calculate the mean of the data points by

```
Sum(data points) / Count(data points)
```

Equal variance:   Calculate the variance of the two different datasets then apply normalization to their data points:

```
  Each Data Point <- Data Point Value - Mean(data points for that dataset) 
                     -----------------------------
                       Standard Deviation for that dataset
```

The standard deviation / variance for the two datasets will be different. By dividing each data point in the respective datasets by their corresponding standard deviation you get more easily comparable results.

E.g. if variance of dataset A is 25  and the variance of dataset B is 100:  each data point in A is then diviced by 5 and the point in B are divided by 10. That allows cross entropy calculation to compare similar-amplitude values.